# MYSQL auto-incrementing grouped results

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I am building a SQL table to hold test results. Each individual test taken will have a `test_id` which is formatted as an integer. I would like to log each question result as a row like such:

| test_id | question | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

**My Question**: Is there an effective way to auto-increment the test_id assuming each test has the same number of questions?

Comment: have two insert function one keeps the last test_id the other increases

Comment: `test_id` implies that it is a unique identifier for a test. This itself implies the existence of a `test` table, with one row per test and a unique `id` column (possibly using an auto increment column). Then the solution to your problem is to create a new test row, pick up that row's unique identifier and use it in this table. In short, trying to do everything in one table is your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below solution. It might be helpful

```
create table tableName(test_id identity(1,1) primary key, question int, score int)
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want a new `test_id` on each row.  Each test will be multiple questions and all questions in the same batch (same test) should have the same `test_id`, then the next batch of questions should have a different `test_id`.  Basically, they need a separate `test` table, with an identity column there.

Comment: also mysql has no identity